# Spring XD to read multiple website data

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-xd

I need to create a website that reads contents of different websites and help to compare them.

One of the examples having a similar website

http://www.mysmartprice.com/mobile/samsung-galaxy-grand-2-msp3633

This helps us to compare prices of samsung mobile between different online websites.

Now I need to know :
1. How to read data from different websites. 
Using java, I can read and fetch html data. But question arises, what is the best way to parse the html content to get desired information?

I want to use Spring XD. Please suggest best strategy?

Regards,
Jubin

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to develop a java application for each data source, and then develop a custom module "source", and use Spring xd to ingest the data.

Another solution is to develop the application, make your applications load required data to csv files and trasfer them into a path like /tmp/xd/input automatically when the program runs, and then use Spring XD to ingest the data from csv files into whatever destination you need.